# Problem when I put float into a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a problem when I put floats in a numpy array.

Here is my code:

```
x=sum([item[0] for item in clusters[k]])/len(clusters[k])
y=sum([item[1] for item in clusters[k]])/len(clusters[k])

centers[k]=np.array([x,y])
```

And this is what I get, when I print x, y and centers:

```
x:
5.029068157893012
y:
4.9725319416514395
x:
1.0273866309343607
y:
0.9492915123013862
x:
8.01021923983273
y:
1.034128622860488

cluster:
[[5 4]
 [1 0]
 [8 1]]
```

I have tried to use:

```
centers[k]=np.array([x,y],dtype=np.float64)
```

without any success...

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What is you question? What is the desired result exactly?

Comment: what I would like is to have :

Comment: ```[[5.029068157893012, 4.9725319416514395],
[1.0273866309343607, 0.9492915123013862],
[8.01021923983273, 1.034128622860488]]
```

Comment: What is the dtype of `centres`?  I'd guess it's `int` of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need the following:

```
import numpy as np

cluster = np.array([[5, 4],
                    [1, 0],
                    [8, 1]])

# Sum each column and divide by the length 
center = np.sum(cluster, axis=0)/len(cluster)

print(center)
# array([4.66666667, 1.66666667])
```

In the case of a multidimensional data set, you can try the following:

```
import numpy as np

clusters = np.array([[[5, 4], [1, 0], [8, 1]],
                     [[5, 4], [1, 0], [8, 1]],
                     [[5, 4], [1, 0], [8, 1]]])

_sum = np.sum(clusters, axis=1)
center = np.array([_sum[k]/len(clusters[k]) for k in range(len(clusters))])
center
```

Comment: well not exactly... what I want is the same cluster array but with float value instead of int, like this:
```
[[5.029068157893012, 4.9725319416514395], 
[1.0273866309343607, 0.9492915123013862],
 [8.01021923983273, 1.034128622860488]]
```

Comment: Can you please show us your clusters, so that I can output exactly these values